# delete by regex rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have some data. I want to delete part of it by a regex rule.
I want to delete any character except for
the period between two number and the number.
Data as follows:

```py
str1 = 'ABC.5,696.05'
str2 = 'xxx3,769.01'
```

**The result should be '5696.05' and '3769.01' .**
I use `re.sub(r'[^\d\.]', '', str1)`. But it can not delete the first '.'.

Comment: You mention that you need to delete any character between two numbers. C is not a number

Comment: @arjunsiva OP meant that they want to remove all characters, including thousands separators, apart from the number and its decimal separator.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(\.)(?=\d)|\D', r'\1', text)`, see https://regex101.com/r/j1xX9c/1

Comment: OP why not use your code and then just delete the first `.`...

Comment: `re.sub(r'^\.', '', re.sub(r'[^\d\.]', '', str1))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That [fails for `66,54,321.123`](https://regex101.com/r/j1xX9c/2) (expected `54321.123`)

Comment: @InSync I would the output from your example expect to be `6654321.123` and I'd use regex for this e.g. [`\.(?<!\d.(?=\d))|[^\d.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/PbcW6t/1) (demo contains `\n` for not skipping lines). Wiktor's regex looks to be good too imho. :)

Comment: Does that mean you only want to get the first number with a fractional part? See https://ideone.com/3wmxzX, is it something you can use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of regex so you can chain methods:

```
>>> float(re.sub('^[^\d]+', '', str1).replace(',', ''))
5696.05

>>> float(re.sub('^[^\d]+', '', str2).replace(',', ''))
3769.01
```

A regex to remove non numeric prefix at the start of the strings and a simple substitution to remove thousands separators.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two stages:

1. Find segment starting and ending with a digit,
2. Replace everything what is not a digit or dot in between.

You can pass callback to `sub`

```py
print(re.sub(r'.*?(\d.+\d).*', lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\d.]|(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)','',x.group()),'ABC.5,696.05'))
# 5696.05
```

Here outer `sub` catches everything between first and last digit into group and passes it into lambda.

Lambda removes:

- not digits or dots: `[^\d.]`,
- dots that are not preceded by digit `(?<!\d)\.`
- dots that are not followed by digit `\.(?!\d)`

Comment: The result should be 5696.05 and 3769.01

Comment: @wtyork, corrected answer for updated conditions.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, yes ;-) Again, thank you for introducing me to it.